# Getting cpu_subtype_t in process that runs under i386 arch

Tags: c, macos, lldb, coredump, mach-o

I'm using some C code to generate coredump file out of Mach-o based process.

However, I'm getting some parsing corruption while loading it by lldb debugger after generating coredump for 32bits process :

```
(lldb) target create --core "/tmp/core_pid_1354"
Core file '/tmp/x/core.1354' (unknown-mach-32) was loaded.
```

This, unknown 32 architecture issue, derived from wrong cpu_subtype in struct mach_header.

In order to get cpu_type + cpu_subtype in the following method :

```
struct current_arch cpuArch = {0};
int mib[CTL_MAXNAME];
size_t mibLen;
size_t cpuTypeSize;
pid_t pid = getpid();
mibLen  = CTL_MAXNAME;
int err = sysctlnametomib("sysctl.proc_cputype", mib, &mibLen);
if (err) {
    log_error("coultn't get mib for cpu type using sysctlnametomib. err = %d ", err);
    return KERN_FAILURE;
}

mib[mibLen] = pid;
mibLen += 0x1;
cpuTypeSize = sizeof(cpuArch.type);
err = sysctl(mib, (u_int)mibLen, &(cpuArch.type), &cpuTypeSize, 0x0, 0x0);
if (err) {
    log_error("coultn't get cpu_type+cpu_subtype for mib using syctl. err = %d ", err);
    return KERN_FAILURE;
}

*cpu_type = cpuArch.type;
*cpu_subtype = cpuArch.subtype;
return KERN_SUCCESS;
```

I've compiled the core dumper tool under universal format (both 32/64 bits). and and when trying it under arch=i386, i get cpu_subtype=0, which is non valid subtype for i386. 
I would expect to get the value of macro CPU_SUBTYPE_386 that defined in machine.h file (=3):

```
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_INTEL(f, m) ((cpu_subtype_t) (f) + ((m) << 4))
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_386                 CPU_SUBTYPE_INTEL(3, 0)
```

any idea what's wrong in my code for getting cpu_subtype_t?

Comment: Are you ever setting the value of `cpuArch.subtype`? It looks like you fetch into `&(cpuArch.type)` only.